# Alter table causing SQL Azure database unavailable

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have to perform the exchange of two tables and it's making my system unavailable for 20 minutes(are many data).

My sample code:

```
query = "DROP TABLE MY_TABLE; ";
query += "EXEC sp_rename MY_TABLE_TEMP, MY_TABLE; ";
query += "ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]";
```

Executed the above statements on a SQL Azure database, and this caused the database unavailable for 20 minutes. Any insights in this?

Comment: I wonder what your question is

Comment: What is your question actually? You giving a statement instead of asking a question

Comment: Sorry. How to not let my sql Unavailable for 20 minutes?

Comment: Please re-write the question so that we, who don't know what you're doing at all, would understand what your problem is. Now the only answer to your question is that don't drop the table.

Comment: Sounds like there are login failures after started executing the command? Is it correct? What edition / SKU you are in? Did you check sys.event_logs to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Was the entire database unavailable or just the table?

Answer (score 0):

Is your DB in the US East? They're having cloud problems, if so.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Answer (score 0):

Azure database can throttle new queries if there is DTU pressure,so i recommend checking below things

1.See DTU status,if any DTU metric is above 90% consistently,then you may need to consider upgrading to higher tier  ,after troubleshooting to see if you can reduce DTU metric

```
SELECT  
    AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Average CPU Utilization In Percent', 
    MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Maximum CPU Utilization In Percent', 
    AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Average Data IO In Percent', 
    MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Maximum Data IO In Percent', 
    AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Average Log Write Utilization In Percent', 
    MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Maximum Log Write Utilization In Percent', 
    AVG(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Average Memory Usage In Percent', 
    MAX(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Maximum Memory Usage In Percent' 
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats;
```

2.See how large you table is ,since you are trying to alter PK,the same value has to be updated in all Non clustered indexes.See the wait stats..